# AJAX submits form, but it won't stop but it insert data into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a message board and inputs forms have to be validated if `javascript` is disabled. If javascript is enabled it has to have AJAX to stop refresh and `submit` form.

I have an html form which is validated by php. And now I'm trying to add `jquery` and `ajax` to stop page refresh.
I added a loading `gif` and inactive inputs field on submit button. But when I add $.ajax gif won't stop spinning and fields won't become active. After I refresh the page I can see that the input data was added to database.

I'm quite new in using `ajax` and maybe you could help me find a solution to my problem.

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // getting input values by id
    var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    // array for input values
    var data = { fullname : fullname,
      message : message };

      //disabled all the text fields
      $('.text').attr('disabled','true'); 
      //show the loading sign
      $('.loading').show();

      // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "validation.php",
        //dataType : 'json',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
          alert('success');
        }
      }).done(function(result) {
        if (result == "")
        form.submit();
        else
        alert(result);
      }).fail(function() {
        alert('ERROR');
      });
    });
  });
```

I get success and input value alert, when I use `dataType : 'json',` I get error alert.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: you have to update the page using the ajax result

Comment: the `form.submit()` inside `success` doesn't make sense. Because ajax already is the replacement for submitting the form.

Comment: put that into `success` callback: `$('.loading').hide();   $('.text').attr('disabled','false');`

Comment: The more correct way to do this is `$("form").submit(...)` not on the button

Comment: also you have twice a success-callback. (first param in `.done()` is the success-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe once you display .gif image than you are not going to hide the same .gif image again although your ajax finished or stop or fail (in any case).

> So, on success of ajax add below two lines to hide .gif and enable text fields.

```
//enabled all the text fields
$('.text').prop("disabled", false);

//hide the loading sign
$('.loading').hide();
```

*Whole code seems like this,*

```
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "validation.php",
   data: data,
   cache: false,
   success: function(data){
      //enabled all the text fields
     $('.text').prop("disabled", false);
     //hidethe loading sign
     $('.loading').hide();
     alert('success');
  }
  });
```

Comment: Why OP Will Use This Answer? *Short Description To This/Any Answer Would Be Better For OP & Other Users To Understand*.

Comment: becaus as he wrote **I am quite new in using ajax and** , so the whole script help him to debug the result.

Comment: This is not the answer of mine question Sony. What Changes You Did To OP Code To Make It Work. If You Point Those Things In Your Answer Will Be Great.

Comment: @partykar , is it now worthy ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The gif hides but the input fields won't become active again.

Comment: use ***$('.text').prop("disabled", false);***

Comment: and please check updated code again , at bottom i have added one more line if you want to submit form on sucess of validate.

Comment: when i used your code, the whole code went into a loop, submiting it over and over again.

Comment: remove the form trigger event....keep your code same as before and just try to hide .GIF and enable text fields using mine code..

Comment: worked perfectly as i wanted. Thank you very much :)